# ctable cell vertical align

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, ctable

I have a table like this:

[image: sample table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}
\begin{document}
\ctable
 [caption=Sample]
 {|p{2cm}|c|}
 {}
 {
  \hline
  some multiline (2 or 3 fields) field & need to vertically center this \\ \hline
  one more field & and this \\ \hline
 }
\end{document}
```

I want cells at the second column to be vertically center aligned. Which is the simplest and best method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `m{2in}` column type rather than `p{2in}` (which centres its contents vertically). This is provided by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array), already loaded by [`ctable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable):

```
\ctable
 [caption=Sample]
 {|m{2cm}|c|}
```

Alternatively, the [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) can also do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\begin{document}
\ctable
 [caption=Sample]
 {|p{2cm}|c|}
 {}
 {
  \hline
  some multiline (2 or 3 fields) field & \multirow{3}*{need to vertically center this} \\ \hline
  one more field & \multirow{2}*{and this} \\ \hline
 }
\end{document}
```